# WPF Binding in ComboBox with UserControl list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, user-controls

In two combobox A and B.
A's ItemsSource is Custom list. and B's ItemsSource is UserControl list.
When manually setting the SelectedItem, A combobox works well, but B combobox UI do not show the selected Item. (In debugging, SelectedItem's value mapping is right, but the combobox B's UI do not be changed.)
All the other structure is same between A and B. What is the reason?

MainWindow.xaml

```
 ...
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FruitList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFruit}"
  DisplayMemberPath="FruitName"  />
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserControlList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUserControl}" DisplayMemberPath="ItemName"  />
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click2"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        FruitList.Add(f1);
        FruitList.Add(f2);
        FruitList.Add(f3);

        UserControlList.Add(u1);
        UserControlList.Add(u2);
        UserControlList.Add(u3);

    }

    Fruit f1 = new Fruit { FruitName = "Apple" };
    Fruit f2 = new Fruit { FruitName = "Banana" };
    Fruit f3 = new Fruit { FruitName = "Lemon" };

    MyUserControl u1 = new MyUserControl { ItemName = "Apple" };
    MyUserControl u2 = new MyUserControl { ItemName = "Banana" };
    MyUserControl u3 = new MyUserControl { ItemName = "Lemon" };

    ObservableCollection<Fruit> _FruitList = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>();
    public ObservableCollection<Fruit> FruitList
    {
        get { return _FruitList; }
        set
        {
            _FruitList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    Fruit _SelectedFruit;
    public Fruit SelectedFruit
    {
        get { return _SelectedFruit; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedFruit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }



    ObservableCollection<MyUserControl> _UserControlList = new ObservableCollection<MyUserControl>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyUserControl> UserControlList
    {
        get
        {
            return _UserControlList;
        }
        set
        {
            _UserControlList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    MyUserControl _SelectedUserControl;
    public MyUserControl SelectedUserControl
    {
        get { return _SelectedUserControl; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedUserControl = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedFruit = f3;
    }

    private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedUserControl = u3;
    }
}

public class Fruit
{
    public string FruitName { get; set; }
}
```

}

UserControl

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please do not ask duplicate questions on Stack Overflow... as you have seen, they will be closed by the community. If you ask a question and feel that you have not received a satisfactory answer, then you can edit your question to provide further information (like you did in your duplicated question). Doing this will put your question back to the top of the 'Newest Unanswered Questions' list, so it will attract more attention.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the good way of achieving this. Better define the ItemTemplate for the combobox to have the UserControl in it like:

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <myControls:MyUserControl/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

and define the class Item

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<Item> _ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsList 
{
    get
    {
        return _ItemsList ;
    }
    set
    {
        _ItemsList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Here DataContext of your UserControl will be `Item` object. you can bind the ItemName within you user control to show it in anyway you want.

in your user control you can have:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks, but xaml exception: Cannot set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate. ...??

Comment: Remove `DisplayMemberPath` you don't need it

Comment: @Tzah Mama, After remove DisplayMemberPath, No exception, but not worked.

Comment: yup remove displaymemberpath

Comment: In my code, 'ItemName' means the usercontrol's some property, So I can not divide Item class and MyUserControl class. Did I mis-understand your answer?

Comment: Hi @TzahMama thanks for the response,but if OP just want to show the Item name then we dont really need the dependency property. Since the DataContext is Item object it can bind the property like in updated answer directly

Comment: @nit, Correct, in my first combo is worked well although not Dependency Property. In your answer, should I insert Item class in my user control??? Please full worked code.

Comment: No you dont need to add item class in user control, Just create list in mainwindow and bind to combobox as showin in the answer. In the usercontrol xaml, you can add the textblock and bind the Text property to ItemName. It will work. Shown in answer

Comment: you need not to bind the user control list to your combobox ideally for two reason.. first your viewmodel should not have UI controls in it and secondly this can be achieved purely through xaml

Comment: @nit I think you mis understand that I want. your answer structure is same with my 'FruitList' that is work well.

Comment: @nit The above my sample code is just sample. So, In my situation, I can not change the usercontrol list and I want to use usercontrol list as combobox's itemssource.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have asked "What is the reason?":

The reason why the second combo box does not show any selection is that `ComboBox` handles items of type `ContentControl` specially. In the read-only selection box, it is not the `ContentControl` that is used to display the value, but the **content of the `ContentControl`**. Since a `UserControl` is a `ContentControl`, the content of the `UserControl` is displayed inside the selection box, and therefore you have lost the data context of the `UserControl`; in the end, an empty string is displayed even though `SelectedItem` contains a reference to the `UserControl` that still has a valid data context. (As far as I know this behavior is undocumented; but you can see that it works like this by examining the ComboBox's code on http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs, especially the UpdateSelectionBoxItem() method).

By setting `IsEditable="True"` on the second ComboBox, you can see that everything works fine if the combo box has no read-only selection box.

Therefore, you generally should avoid adding UI elements to combo boxes, especially if you are using the `DisplayMemberPath` property, i.e. if you never want to actually display the UI element.

The recommended way to display ComboBox items with non-standard appearance (e.g. with UserControls) is described in the answer of @nit.

If you, however, insist on passing a `UserControl` item list to the ComboBox, you might remove `DisplayMemberPath` and use something like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserControlList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUserControl}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Furthermore, in the constructor of your UserControl, you must place this line:

```
((FrameworkElement) Content).DataContext = this;
```

This is necessary to make sure that the correct data context is available in the read-only selection box, which only contains the content of the user control, not the user control itself.

Please note, that with the above example, the drop-down list contains text only (i.e. the item names), but the selection box will contain the fully rendered user control.